# Prevent duplication in ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I have made a simple application in Visual studio using C# that basically browses a folder, and the path of folder comes in text box - 'HideFolderAddress'. When the button 'AddToListBtn' is clicked it checks if there is a presence of the same item and if not it adds the item to list.

But this Prevent duplication in list view does not seems working! Can some one help me?

```
private void BrowsHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

   if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {    
      HideFolderAddress.Text = fd.SelectedPath;
      HideFolderAddress.Tag = Path.GetFileName(fd.SelectedPath);        
   }
}

private void AddToListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListViewItem itemList = new ListViewItem(HideFolderAddress.Tag.ToString());

   if (!FolderList.Items.ContainsKey(HideFolderAddress.Tag.ToString()))
   {            
      itemList.SubItems.Add(HideFolderAddress.Text);
      FolderList.Items.Add(itemList);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it this way , because there will be no key if it is not created via Add method of ListViewItemCollection.

```
    private void AddToListBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string itemTag = HideFolderAddress.Tag.ToString();
         if (!FolderList.Items.ContainsKey(itemTag ))
         {
               ListViewItem itemList = FolderList.Items.Add(itemTag , itemTag , -1);
               itemList.SubItems.Add(HideFolderAddress.Text);
         }
     }
```